# What is the difference between make nconfig & make linux-nconfig?

Tags: linux-kernel, buildroot

I am using buildroot and did not see a difference between:

```
make nconfig
```

and

```
make linux-nconfig
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: Former for Buildroot configuration itself, second for a *linux* package, but since you don't see the difference it might be just an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make nconfig` runs the configuration of Buildroot itself (i.e. selecting which packages to build, which architecture, which toolchain, etc). `make linux-nconfig` runs the configuration of the Linux kernel. It will first download and extract the kernel, and then run the kernel Kconfig infrastructure. It allows you to select CPU, drivers, filesystems etc.

Comment: Does changes in the linux kernel .config (e.g. new packages) have influence on the buildroot .config?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the linux kernel .config doesn't configure packages, it configures kernel options. It's pretty much orthogonal to the Buildroot .config.